# Selection Sort in C is not showing the right output

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, selection-sort

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


void selection_sort(int array[],int num);

int main(void) {

    int i,num;

    printf("Write the number of elements :");
    scanf("%d",&num);

    int array[100];

    for(i=0;i<num;i++){

        scanf("%d",&array[i]);
    }

    selection_sort(array,num);

    return 0;
}

//Doing selection sort algorithm :

void selection_sort(int array[],int num){

    int i,j,min,temp;

    for (i=0;i<num;i++){

        min=i;

        for(j=i+1;j<num;j++){

            if (array[j]<array[i]){

                min=j;
            }
        }

        if (min!=i){

            temp=array[i];
            array[i]=min;
            min=temp;
        }
    }

    printf("Sorted elements :\n");

    for (i=0;i<num;i++){

        printf("%d\n",array[i]);
    }


}
```

please let me know why i am unable to display the sorted elements

Comment: What did you do after you found out your program doesn't work as expected? Did you try anything to debug it yourself? Either by running the program in a debugger and/or adding debug print statements? If so, what did you find? [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Don't you mean array[i]=array[min]; array[min]=temp; ?

Comment: One advise: `int array[]` is IMHO a lie, because you don't pass an array to the function. What this actually is is `int* array`, so changes inside the function affect the array on the caller's site. Just so you know, some people prefer this style though.

Comment: One advise: `int array[]` is IMHO a lie, because you don't pass an array to the function. What this actually is is `int* array`, so changes inside the function affect the array on the caller's site. Just so you know, some people prefer this style though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the part how swap is implemented.

The correct way to swap the elements is:

```
if (min!=i){

    temp=array[i];
    array[i]=array[min];
    array[min]=temp;
}
```

Look at the following corrected code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


void selection_sort(int array[],int num);

int main(void) {

    int i,num;

    printf("Write the number of elements :");
    scanf("%d",&num);

    int array[100];

    for(i=0;i<num;i++){

        scanf("%d",&array[i]);
    }

    selection_sort(array,num);

    return 0;
}

//Doing selection sort algorithm :

void selection_sort(int array[],int num){

    int i,j,min,temp;

    for (i=0;i<num;i++){

        min=i;

        for(j=i+1;j<num;j++){

            if (array[j]<array[i]){

                min=j;
            }
        }

        if (min!=i){

            temp=array[i];
            array[i]=array[min];
            array[min]=temp;
        }
    }

    printf("Sorted elements :\n");

    for (i=0;i<num;i++){

        printf("%d\n",array[i]);
    }


}
```